# Chart JS , Unir puntos undefined

Tags: html5, canvas, chart.js

Hay momentos donde mi sistema recibe nulls o undefined. Necesito que cuando tenga datos null o undefined se traze la unión entre estos puntos con una linea de otro color.

**Actual**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Esperado**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [
            {
            fill: false,
            label: 'test',
            data: [22, 29, 33,undefined, 55, 52, 33],
            backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            borderColor: "red",
            borderWidth: 2
            
        }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
```

**Jsfiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/palaceslittle/sehf31cy/1/

Answer (score 0):

Si eliminas del origen de datos esos elementos nulos o sin definir, obtendrás un resultado interpolado semejante a lo que buscas.

El problema actual, es que esos valores no pueden ser interpretados por la librería y causan una ruptura en la gráfica. La mejor opción es sanitizar/limpiar los datos que utilizas como origen para que la gráfica se pinte adecuadamente.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [
            {
            fill: false,
            label: 'test',
            data: [22, 29, 33,undefined, 55, 52, 33].filter(function(x){return x !== undefined && x !== null}),
            backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            borderColor: "red",
            borderWidth: 2
            
        }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
```

Usando la función `filter` del `Array` nos permite limpiar el array de datos de forma sencilla.

---

Cambiar los valores `undefined` o `null` a 0. Modificamos el color de los puntos que no tengan valor.

```js
var data = [22, 29, 33,undefined, 55, 52, 33];
var default_color = 'red';
var undefined_color = 'black';

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [
            {
            fill: false,
            label: 'test',
            data: cleanData(data),
            backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            pointBackgroundColor: getPointColors(data),
            borderColor: "red",
            borderWidth: 2
            
        }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});

function cleanData(data) {
   var data_cleaned = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       if (data[i] === undefined || data[i] === null) {
           data_cleaned.push(0);
       } else {
           data_cleaned.push(data[i]);
       }
   }
   return data_cleaned;
};

function getPointColors(data) {
   var point_colors = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       if (data[i] === undefined || data[i] === null) {
           point_colors.push(undefined_color);
       } else {
           point_colors.push(default_color);
       }
   }
   return point_colors;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hola!, antes que nada gracias. En mi sistema es importante mostrar que en esos instantes hubo valores "undefined", es decir, si o si debo mostrar que no hubieron datos, pero también necesito que la línea continúe como represente en la imagen.
 ¿No existe manera de poder darle dos colores a la recta?

Comment: @nawelittle Se puede cambiar el color de los puntos, pero creo que no se puede cambiar el color del área o de la línea. De todos modos, si no tienes valor, como lo va a pintar? Es decir, como representas la ausencia de valor en una gráfica que muestra puntos y junta líneas en base a unos valores? Lo único que se me ocurre es ponerles un valor de `0` para que no falte el punto pero te muestre el valor negativo.

Comment: Yo podría eliminar los undefined o cambiarlos a otro valor, pero debería mostrar en el gráfico que en esos instantes no hubo datos y unir los puntos. Lo importante sería que de alguna manera pueda señalar en el gráfico que en esos instantes no hubo datos.

Comment: @nawelittle Parece más una duda de diseño que un problema de programación entonces. Todo dependería de como y por qué necesitas representar la ausencia de valor. Personalmente, la interrupción de la gráfica me parece la mejor forma de representar la ausencia como destacarla. Mejor paso esto al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67877/https-es-stackoverflow-com-questions-113352-chart-js-unir-puntos-undefined).

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas interpolar un punto medio entre el hueco, este ejemplo solo sirve si tienes un "hueco" de "1 espacio"(A los lados de un hueco hay valor) como en tu ejemplo:

```js
var data = [22, 29, 33,undefined, 55, 52, 33];

var holes = data.reduce( (arr, el, index) => {
  if(isNaN(el)){
    arr[index - 1] = data[index - 1];
    arr[index] = (data[index - 1] + data[index + 1])/2;
    arr[index + 1] = data[index + 1];
  } else {
    arr.push(undefined);
  }
  return arr;
}, []);

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [
            {
            fill: false,
            label: 'test',
            data: data,
            backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            borderColor: "red",
            borderWidth: 2
            
        },
        {
            fill: false,
            label: 'test',
            data: holes,
            backgroundColor:'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
            borderColor: "gray",
            borderWidth: 2
            
        }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Es un buen truco el meter otro dataset para poder jugar con los colores, haciendo que lo que interrumpe una, lo rellene otro. No obstante, ese punto intermedio no falsea los datos? Es decir, para esa etiqueta/tiempo/loquesea no se ha tenido un valor de 40,X y la gráfica así parece indicarlo.

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres decir. Como busca el Op, la solución es una forma representativa de decir que ahí no hubo dato. De cualquier otra forma, con otra aproximación, también estarías falseando la gráfica, ya que no tienes el dato "real" o "medido". Me he intentado ceñir a lo que pide la pregunta. De todas formas comento que no es una solución que sirva para todos los casos. @frikinside . Saludos!

Comment: Correcto, la respuesta se intenta ceñir todo lo posible a lo que pide la pregunta, ahí no hay queja jeje. Pero has tenido que añadir un punto adicional (P.D. Igual marcarle el `fill` a `true` puede enmascarar algo más el punto como indicativo de que no hay datos en esa sección). No obstante, por un intento de ayudar a OP con su problema, a mi modo de ver, no hay problema, la interrupción es la forma más fiel de representar la ausencia de valor (o establecer valor nulo). Al menos a mi modo de ver.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo. De todas formas, no conocemos al 100% qué quiere representar. Igual, necesita representar los datos de forma que tengan "continuidad" indicando los intervalos donde no hay valor. Por ejemplo se me ocurre, estar representando una ruta con un punto cada 2 metros,  hay puntos donde no has obtenido datos (del GPS por ejemplo). Necesitas representar la ruta indicando donde no has tenido señal. Sabes el punto inicial (donde perdiste la señal), el final (donde la recuperaste), pero no lo que hay entre medias.

Comment: Buen ejemplo, pero en esos casos lo que se hace es interpolar en base a tendencias o simplemente unir los puntos con los valores intermedios (como hace ya mismamente ChartJS). En el GPS sabe que el camino no desaparece y que continua y se interpolan los puntos para "averiguar" el camino a seguir. No es problemático por que hay una tendencia progresiva. Pero en una monitorización (por ejemplo), simplemente se ignoran los puntos de los que se carecen y se dibuja la línea en base a los puntos que si tenemos.  Como bien dices, depende del caso de uso del OP.